# What is the relationship name of my in-law's sister/brother and their children?

Tags: word-usage, history

I want to know how to call few relations like:  my

> brother-in-law's sister
>
> brother-in-law's sister's son/daughter
>
> sister-in-law's brother
>
> sister-in-law's brother's son/daughter

Comment: not really one word.. for eg. my mom's brother means.. i can call him as uncle and my sister's child means i can call them as Nephew and niece right.. like that i want to know how can i call these relations?

Comment: English, in general, has [relatively few kinship terms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616) compared to many other languages.

Answer (score 2):

I just consulted my mentor whom is studying in the Ministry of Education in Singapore.

Brother-in-law's sister is basically sister-in-law. That's the shortest. For their son or daughter, either distant cousins or cousins-in-law, but I would not parse the latter.

Answer (score 0):

> brother-in-law's sister

Sister-in-law

> brother-in-law's sister's son/daughter

Sister-in-law's son/daughter

> sister-in-law's brother

Brother-in-law

> sister-in-law's brother's son/daughter

Brother-in-law's son/daughter.

But mostly we just call them the animals that run around screaming, and knocking stuff over while their good-for-nothing parents drink our beer and laugh at their antics.